# New Promise is not working with db.transaction

Tags: javascript, async-await, react-native-sqlite-storage

Im working with sqlite (react-native-sqlite-storage) in React-native and I have a problem with promises at the moment I want to close the database:

```
    this.dataUsuarios= await fetchData(this.url);    
    db = await openDB();
    await this.insertarDatos();
    db.close();
```

The thing is that it gives me a problema when db.close is executed because this.insertarDatos() is processing still but idk why. I think my new promise should work!

```
insertarDatos = () =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, rejection)=>{
      db.transaction((tx) => {
          for(let i in this.dataUsuarios){
            const sql = `INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES (
              ${this.dataUsuarios[i].id}, 
              '${this.dataUsuarios[i].nombre}',
              '${this.dataUsuarios[i].usuario}',
              '${this.dataUsuarios[i].password}',
              ${this.dataUsuarios[i].grupo},
              '${this.dataUsuarios[i].faenas}'
            );`;
            tx.executeSql(sql, [],  this.successCB(i), this.errorCB);
          }
      },resolve,rejection);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't `transaction` already return a promise by itself?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a problem with promises, does it work when you use callback style? Unfortunately `transaction` is really poorly documented - I don't see any indication that it waits for the processing to finish.

Comment: Nitpick, if you're using the method like `this.insertarDatos();` and not passing it as a prop to a child component, it's better to declare the method like `insertarDatos () { ... }` so that it's not making a copy of the function for each instance of your component.

Comment: Just a guess but I would imagine you need to "promisify" all the way down like `return new Promise((r, j) => tx.executeSql(sql, [], () => { this.successCB(i)(); r(); }, () => { this.errorCB(); j(); }));`

Answer (score 0):

as of the time of writing this `db.transaction` takes the error call back first, where you are passing the `resolve`

here is an example :

```
// sqlite transactions don't play with promises nicely.
// the fn param here shouldn't use promises.
const transactional = async (fn: (tx: Transaction) => void) => {
  const db = await getDb();
  const x = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const trans = db.transaction(fn, (e) => {
      console.log('transaction failed ')
      reject(e)
    },
    () => {
      console.log('transaction finished ok')
      resolve();
    });
  });
  await x;
};
```